# Cordova InAppBrowser wont redirect on android

Tags: android, cordova, inappbrowser

I am working on cordova application and I am using the InAppBrowser plugin.

On android I am opening an external login page with the InAppBrowser, when the login process is done the page redirects to a given redirect_url.

However, it seems that the InAppBrowser url is'nt changing.

I checked it on IOS and it was working fine. On older Android devices it is also working fine but when trying it on Android 8.0 the InAppBrowser url doesn't get redirected.

I already tried changing some of the InAppBrowser initial settings.

this.ref = window.cordova.InAppBrowser.open(this.props.url, '_blank',      'clearcache=yes,clearsessioncache=yes,hardwareback=no,toolbar=no,location=no');
      this.ref.addEventListener('loadstop', this.checkFinished);

```
checkFinished = ()=>{
  this.ref.executeScript({code:"document.location.toString().indexOf(\"api/success\") >=0 && " +
    "JSON.parse(document.getElementsByTagName(\"script\")[0].innerHTML.replace(\"parent.postMessage(JSON.stringify(\",\"\").replace(\"), '*');\",\"\"))\n"}, (result)=>{
    if (result && result.length >0 && result[0].token){
      this.ref.close();
      this.close({result:result[0]});
    } else {
      // this.$timeout(this.checkFinished(),300);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Please provide code.

Comment: same issue here. you ever find a solution?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/issues/776
No solution yet;